# Windows XP Style Button

Tags: mfc, visual-styles

How can I get a Windows XP-style button in my MFC dialog?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to add a [manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289524(VS.71).aspx) to your project.

Check out this article: [Using Windows XP Styles in your MFC/WIN32 Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/xpstylemfc.aspx)